# Why is File.read('/path/to/file') not in Ruby docs?

Tags: ruby

Why is the `File.read` method not documented in http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/File.html when it clearly exists:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> File.read('readme.md')
=> "hello world"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is documented:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/IO.html#method-c-read

The method is inherited from `IO` though.

Comment: What is the default encoding for this method when it returns a string?

Answer (score 6):

Use Ruby to investigate:

```
File.methods.include? :read
 #=> true 
File.methods(false).include? :read                                                                    
 #=> false 
File.ancestors
 #=> [File, IO, File::Constants, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject] 
IO.methods(false).include? :read
 #=> true
```

Answer (score 4):

It goes even easier :

```
File.method(:read)
#=> #<Method: File(IO).read>

['array'].method(:flatten)
#=> #<Method: Array#flatten>
```

If present, the class or module between parenthesis is the place where the method is defined.

For class methods, the syntax is `Class.method`.

For instance methods, the syntax is `Class#method`.

So `#<Method: File(IO).read>` means that `read` is a class method, defined in `IO` and available to the `File` class.

For a method that has been defined in plain Ruby (and not C), you can use `Method#source_location`:

```
require 'set'
Set.new.method(:replace).source_location
#=> ["~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/set.rb", 142]
```

So `Set#replace` is defined in the specified Ruby file, at line 142.

If you use [PRY](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Source-browsing) as an alternative to IRB, you can even use :

```
show-source Set#replace
#=> 
From: /home/ricou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/set.rb @ line 142:
Owner: Set
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 10

def replace(enum)
  if enum.instance_of?(self.class)
    @hash.replace(enum.instance_variable_get(:@hash))
  else
    clear
    merge(enum)
  end

  self
end
```

Comment: Excellent answer Eric, thanks for sharing- I didn't know about these techniques. Also quite useful is [Method#owner](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Method.html#method-i-owner) i.e. `File.method(:read).owner #=> #<Class:IO>` and `['array'].method(:flatten).owner #=> Array`.

Comment: This is a very compelling feature of PRY